# If C = A + B and E = D + C, is it necessarily the case that E = D + A + B?

Tags: patent-infringement, novelty, non-obviousness

If some other invention claims `A + D` or `B + D`, would the examiner argue that these are not novel because `E = D + C` already exist, and `C = A + B`, hence `E = D + A + B` necessarily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn’t what some other patent *claims*. That is not key to what you can patent. It is what another patent, or journal article or rejected but published patent application *discloses*. For novelty or obviousness claims are not compared to claims but to what is publicly known and published.

Some of your puzzles are not the puzzles you imagine they are.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only answering the question as posed in the title since that is more clearly stated.

> If C = A + B and E = D + C, is it necessarily the case that E = D + A + B?

As an abstract logic problem the answer is yes. In real life patent claims, the claim language is never so simple and interpretation is informed by the specification. So the answer to your question may not apply.